# Lombok Builder is not working

Tags: java, lombok

I have a base class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class FurnitureBillingRequest implements JSONAble<FurnitureBillingRequest> {

    private static final Gson gsonSerializer;

    static {
        gsonSerializer = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    }

    @Expose
    protected String name;

    @Expose
    protected long date;

    @Expose
    protected String phone;

    @Expose
    protected List<BillItemRO> items;

    @Expose
    protected int totalAmount;

    @Expose
    protected int amountPaid;

    @Expose
    protected String remark;

    @Expose
    protected String address;

    public FurnitureBillingRequest(String name, long date, String phone, int totalAmount,
                                   int amountPaid, String remark, String address) {
        this(name, date, phone, new ArrayList<>(), totalAmount, amountPaid, remark, address);
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return gsonSerializer.toJson(this);
    }

    public FurnitureBillingRequest toObject(String json) {
        return gsonSerializer.fromJson(json, FurnitureBillingRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {

        if (!(that instanceof FurnitureBillingRequest)) {
            return false;
        }

        FurnitureBillingRequest thatFurnitureBillingRequest = (FurnitureBillingRequest) that;

        if (!StringUtils.equals(this.name, thatFurnitureBillingRequest.name)) return false;

        if (this.date != thatFurnitureBillingRequest.date) return false;

        if (!StringUtils.equals(this.phone, thatFurnitureBillingRequest.phone)) return false;

        if (!this.items.equals(thatFurnitureBillingRequest.items)) return false;

        if (this.totalAmount != thatFurnitureBillingRequest.totalAmount) return false;

        if (this.amountPaid != thatFurnitureBillingRequest.amountPaid) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

And a subclass extending as following

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UpdateBillRequest extends FurnitureBillingRequest {

    private static final Gson gsonSerializer;

    static {
        gsonSerializer = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    }

    @Expose
    private String uid;

    @Builder
    public UpdateBillRequest(String uid, String name, long date, String phone, List<BillItemRO> items, int totalAmount, int amountPaid, String remark, String address) {
        super(name, date, phone, items, totalAmount, amountPaid, remark, address);
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public UpdateBillRequest(String uid, String name, long date, String phone, int totalAmount, int amountPaid, String remark, String address) {
        super(name, date, phone, totalAmount, amountPaid, remark, address);
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return gsonSerializer.toJson(this);
    }

    public FurnitureBillingRequest toObject(String json) {
        return gsonSerializer.fromJson(json, FurnitureBillingRequest.class);
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test to check if json is created well.

```
public class UpdateBillRequestTest {

    @Test
    public void toJson() {

        UpdateBillRequest request = UpdateBillRequest.builder()
                .date(1234567868L)
                .uid("9i09909-90i90-8u90")
                .name("kuldeep")
                .phone("9535580366")
                .build();

        System.out.println(request.toJson());
    }

    @Test
    public void toObject() {
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile the code it ends up into errors

[ERROR] /Users/kuldeep/Work/Repositories/billing/BillingModel/src/main/java/com/tarkshala/services/lambda/model/UpdateBillRequest.java:[24,5] builder() in com.tarkshala.services.lambda.model.UpdateBillRequest cannot override builder() in com.tarkshala.services.lambda.model.FurnitureBillingRequest
[ERROR]   return type com.tarkshala.services.lambda.model.UpdateBillRequest.UpdateBillRequestBuilder is not compatible with com.tarkshala.services.lambda.model.FurnitureBillingRequest.FurnitureBillingRequestBuilder

I have no idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I guess that since `builder()` is defined in the super-class, it will return an instance of the super-class. Have you tried also adding `@Builder` to the sub-class?

Comment: Well, seems you can't add `@Builder` to the sub-class, and casting won't work, either...

Comment: Then it looks like Lombok's limitation. Any particular reason for designing lombok like this?

Comment: `public FooBuilder builder()` in `Foo` and `public BarBuilder builder()` in `Bar extends Foo`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn couldn't get your point. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in Java. Try to compile this code:

```
class Foo {
    public static FooBuilder builder() {
        return new FooBuilder();
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    public static BarBuilder builder() {
        return new BarBuilder();
    }
}
class FooBuilder {
    public Foo build() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
class BarBuilder {
    public Bar build() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

Classic builder pattern, but I omitted all properties.

Now eclipse tells me that "The return type is incompatible with Foo.builder()" for `Bar.builder()`

You can't have overload methods with incompatible return types. This even applies to static methods.

Comment: In other words, the problem is that while `Bar` extends `Foo`, `BarBuilder` does not extend `FooBuilder` (and neither do those created by Lombok), thus incompatible types.

Comment: Yes. While it might be possible to keep track of `@Builder` annotations from superclasses, it would also introduce a lot of complexity. The best action would be to use `@Builder(builderMethodName="fooBuilder")`